# Geany not giving output in c language

Tags: c, compiler-errors, geany

I saved the prgram by the name main.c in the d drive and the output screen shows the following error

```
"./main" is not recognised as an internal or external command,operable program or batch file.
-----------------------------------------------------
Program exited with code :9009
```

What can i do to get a proper output
Os:windows 10

Comment: The os is windows

Comment: Just checking: Have you compiled the program, or did you just put the source code in main.c and expect to be able to run it?

Answer (score 0):

Please mention the operating system in which you are running your command.When the environment variables get messed up, it could lead to trouble with other programs that share the same environment variable. Your problem refers to the symptom of one such problem.Have you provided the compiler with the environment variable and edited the path variable?There may be the problem that is why it is not recognised as a command.Try theses links below in case of windows-:
https://www.google.co.in/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=3&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=0ahUKEwjB8cayspvSAhUiR48KHYN9BaMQFggkMAI&url=http%3A%2F%2Fhelpdeskgeek.com%2Fhow-to%2Ffix-not-recognized-as-an-internal-or-external-command%2F&usg=AFQjCNH9Y6HRIzrNIvIP-dXmoE6S2BzcBg&sig2=hdboN8vE_TvLJAwG8ca2kw
http://www.c4learn.com/c-programming/run-c-program-command-prompt-windows/